# Translating Stata commands into R (Stochastic Frontier Analysis)

Tags: r, stata

I have very little familiarity with Stata, and I am working on interpreting the code below (which concerns stochastic frontier analysis) in order to translate into R:

```
frontier lq lland lseed llabor, distribution(exponential)
predict double u_e, u
gen eff = exp(-u_e)
.sum eff
```

I am having trouble finding the meanings of two parts of this code:

`u_e`

`exp()`

What do these refer to? I understand that `exp(x)` returns the "elementwise exponentiation" of `x`, and I understand that `u_e` is somehow related to the error term, but I do not understand what they are well enough to know how to translate them in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`u_e` is just the name supplied for a new variable. What's important is that it contains estimates of minus the natural log of the technical efficiency via E(u|e)

Hence `exp(-u_e)` is just the estimated technical efficiency.

See https://www.stata.com/manuals/rfrontierpostestimation.pdf